# Rework with a coating over the solder joint

Tags: rework, conformal-coating

I've got a simple board to repair (a switch/junction board for a fancy bike light).  The wires to a DC connector broke because of insufficient strain relief.

It's a trivial job, except there's a paint-like coating on top of the solder joints.  I've come across conformal coatings all over high-spec SMD boards, but nothing quite like this partial coating over big joints before.  It's not for waterproofing because the switch on the other side of the board is a simple surface mount push-button, not sealed; the housing is the (moderately) waterproof bit.

It scrapes off the flat surface of the board but not so well off the actual solder.  I'm wary of just sticking an iron on it, mainly fumes but also contaminating the new joint.

[image: coated PCB]

Currently I'm thinking of picking off what I can then working somewhere very well ventilated, but is there a better approach ?

Comment: Have you tried to dissolve the coating in something like flux remover or even just acetone?

Comment: Have you tried to identify the connector to see if you can't just buy a fresh one for $5?

Comment: @Hearth not yet. I don't have flux remover at home but I do have acetone

Comment: @DKNguyen it's the board that's the problem - the wires attachment has failed; the connector is fine.  Replacement boards aren't available, so for a board with a BOM cost  <<$1,  a light costing over $100 would be ruined

Comment: Oh I misinterpreted what the photo was

Comment: @Hearth acetone is pretty good where I can scrub it, so at least I'll have far less burning off.  I'd rather not immerse the whole board for a long soak .  I wasn't expecting it to be that easy to dissolve

Comment: If it's that expensive, and you don't mind waiting a bit for shipping, you may want to consider making a replacement PCB. Measure the original one, duplicate the layout in KiCad (or your EDA of choice), and send off the gerbers to a company like PCBway or JLCPCB who can make a tiny PCB like this for probably less than $10 (plus shipping). Then just replace the whole thing.

Comment: Chris , I found a similar problem with a 30 W waterprotected aluminum cast LED floodlight  with a 1" round LED, battery and charger. Someone put it on the curb for dead. I took it home and found the AC wire inside like this one broken from inadequate strain relief.. So I replaced the whole cordset and bypassed the problem area with a spare cordset.  It was a coincidence seeing this. It's a great floodlamp with battery pack inside or AC plugin, but the cordset wire was stressed too much. Good luck fixing it, , the PCB is not worth repairing for the AC interface. Find a better way.

Comment: @Hearth after your tip on acetone got most of it off (and softened the rest, so I could pick some more off), I seem to have a robust repair and no unusual fumes.  It's a favour for a friend, so a whole replacement board would change things dramatically. There are a few components on the other side, apart from the switch - an LED and what appears to be a photodiode, plus some (probably just resistors) hidden under the coating